# Add "embed Balsamiq mockups" to the 10-rep permission description

Tags: bug

Because embedding Balsamiq mockups isn't a feature shared with to the other SE sites, it doesn't seem to have made its way into the UX.SE [descriptions of permissions granted at 10 rep](https://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user).  If possible, it should be added to that page.

This will both

1. help relatively new users to realize that they are able to embed mockups.
2. help more senior users recognize that entirely new users can't embed mockups.

Comment: It's *kind of* linked it with the ability to add images, as they are really just images, but I do agree - it's a specific feature of this site so should be clearer in the permissions that this is the reputation limit where it's enabled.